# How is 1 a member of the Kaprekar series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Using the definitions at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number); [Sloane](http://oeis.org/A006886); and [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KaprekarNumber.html); I can't see why $1$ is a member of the Kaprekar series?

Would someone give an easy explanation?

Thanks.

(Yet more on this [here](http://paddy3118.blogspot.com/2011/06/woa-glitch-on-wolfram-mathworld.html)).

Comment: Thanks DJC for the restoration of the links. I'm new so the spam filter (quite correctly) limited the number of links I could create).

Comment: **Found what I was after**: [The Kaprekar numbers](http://pictor.math.uqam.ca/~plouffe/OEIS/jis/The%20Kaprekar%20Numbers.pdf) by D.E.Iannucci says 1 is included by fiat!

Comment: I don't see what an Italian auto manufacturer has to do with it. $1$ is included because it satisfies the definitions, as both answerers agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1=0+1$, $1^2=0\times10^m+1$ seems to fit the definition as given at the OEIS reference.

Comment: It also fits the definition given at Wikipedia.

Comment: If we set m to its minimum i.e. 1; q is `0`, so r is 1. Then r is **not** `<(10^1)` ?

Comment: @Paddy3118, I don't understand. $10^1=10$, so, if $r=1$, then certainly $r\lt10^1$.

Comment: Umm, your right. But I do like the Iannucci paper just stating it is 'cos it is :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, my answer is anticlimactic. I happen to know wikipedia's definition (linked in the question, but I reproduce the definition here)

> Let X be a non-negative integer. X is a Kaprekar number for base b if there exist non-negative integers n, A, and positive number B satisfying:
>       $X^2 = Ab^n + B$, where $0 < B < b^n$, and s.t. 
>       $X = A + B$

So $A$ can be $0$. Thus $1^2 = 1 = 0* 10^1 + 1$, and we see that it's a Kaprekar number.

And - Gerry posted his answer just before me (I refreshed, and it's there)! But I wrote this too, so I'll keep it -

Comment: There is no need to sign your name at the end, since it appears at the bottom anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately the WP article goes on to state the `0<B<N` with the minimum N being 1 so B cannot be 1 ? (the range on OEIS is slightly different - and in the WP nomenclature becomes `0<=B<N`).

Comment: @Paddy - this doesn't really matter, as it could just be 2 instead. Then we still see that 1 is such an example, as A is 0. That's the important part.

Comment: Yep. I now see where I was wrong. Thanks.